# MIPS Jump Instruction in machine language

Tags: mips

I want to convert the instruction `jal 0x1041001C` to machine language.
I found the next algorithm:

1. Erase the left number of the hex address (so we'll get `0x041001C`)
2. Shift right 2 (so we'll get in binary `(00 0001 0000 0100 0000 0000 0111)`)
3. Opcode of `jal` instruction (in hex) is 3.

So we'll get the binary code: `(0000 1100 0001 0000 0100 0000 0000 0111)`

and in hex: `0x0C104007`

but by the web - https://www.eg.bucknell.edu/~csci320/mips_web/

I get that the hex code should be `0x0C41001C`.

Where is my mistake? maybe the algorithm isn't correct?

Comment: Your answer looks correct. It looks like the web page is not doing the right shift.